# What is the preferred way to embed an SWF graphic in a Flex 4 application?

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

In Flex 3, you just said

```
<mx:Image source="@Embed('foo.swf')"/>
```

What is the preferred way to do this with Flex 4?  Should I just keep using Image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image tag is for loading "Image" formats along with swf. You can go also go with SWFLoader. Flex 4 is still Beta. I would go with Image or SWFLoader, preferbaly the second one.

and I am sure this wont get changed in Flex 4 too.

Comment: I agree with using the Swfloader - if will provide functionality specific to swfs that can be helpful